# Do I need to a new CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") for each request or should I store it for the lifetime of my spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

When a button is clicked in Excel, I do a GET:

```
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
    End With
```

This is some code I grabbed from an example.

This sheet will do quite a lot of API related calls. Should I be storing the hReq as a global object and creating it once, or once per button click?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you cannot reuse it. I did in the past and there was no problem. Just be careful sometimes global variables have a way of loosing reference. You can encapsulate getting the reference in a function using `GetObject` and if that returns an error you can create another one.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Good point. Looing reference can especially occur if you use `End` or push the stop button in VBE twice.

Comment: @Nibbly If you use that in a loop (sending one request after another) I would **definitly** create the object only once to safe resources. • In other cases this is more a question of how you like it and usability. As SuperSymmetry said, the goblal variable can lose the object in some occations so you need to handle this case. That means sometimes it's easier to recreate the object everytime you use it. I would say it depends on how time critic your action is and how often you would have to recreate that object. Very opinion based I would say.

Comment: Consider using a class. I would generally avoid auto-instantiation as it can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @QHarr could you explain what you mean by consider using a class?

Comment: Here is a very contrived example. You would run the code in module 3. The class is instantiated on Workbook_Open. You can then access the same object throughout your code until you set http = Nothing. https://pastebin.com/6HSQhYsA

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim hReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP '* Requires tools reference to `Microsoft XML, v3.0`

With hReq
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
End With
```

Given remarks about losing reference, may I point out putting `New` in the `Dim` statement will create a new object if the old one is lost.

Aside from that you may recycle this object.

Comment: Good point with the `As New`, but in this case you would replace `Dim` by `Private` or `Public` and make it a global variable. That would make much more sense.

Comment: Great! Absolutely correct, but I got the impression OP was only using late binding.